# CSS custom cursor not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, cursor

i have made a css, which is supposed to have a custom cursor. The image files are .png and .cur and both are 32x32. However they only work on firefox. In edge the alternative cursor is used. How do i fix it? here is the code:

```
body {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("cyan_magenta_colors-wide.jpg");
        background-color: #cccccc;
        font-family: Comic Sans MS;
        width: 99%;
        cursor: url("banoscursorsmall.png"), url("banoscursorsmall.cur"), zoom-in;
```

The zoom in is just to check if it works

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples I found in the page linked below, I suggest you try to add "auto" at the end.

```
cursor: url("banoscursorsmall.png"), url("banoscursorsmall.cur"), auto, zoom-in;
```

[CSS : cursor property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Comment: Well, i thought i tried having only auto, but apparently, now it worked. Thank you :) have no idea what was wrong tho :D